# random number generator statistics

Tags: statistics

A random number generator has produced the following sample from the uniform distribution on $(0,1): Y_1=.12, Y_2=.87, Y_3=.61.$ Use this and the recipe in (b) of the Special Transformation Theorem to simulate a sample of size 3 from the exponential distribution with mean 1.

Special Transformation Theorem: (b) Let $Y$ have the uniform distribution on the interval $(0,1)$ and let $X$ be defined by $Y=F(X)$. Then $X$ has cdf $F(X)$.

I know that $$f_y(y)={1,~~ 0< y < 1}\\
                  f_y(y)={0, ~~\text{otherwise}}$$

Do I use this to set up an integral for $y_1, y_2$ and $y_3?$ I guess I don't know where to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wants you to use the inverse-transform method.

This method is based on the fact that if you have a random variable, X, with CDF $F(x)$, then $F(X)\sim Uniform(0,1)$, for any choice of F(x).

In your case, you know that $Y \sim Uniform(0,1) = F_{exponential}(X)$ where X is exponentially distributed with mean 1.

Therefore, $F^{-1}_{exponential}(Y) = X$

The above is saying that if you transform a uniform(0,1) random varibale using the inverse CDF, the resulting varibale will have the same distribution as the distribution function.

The exponential CDF is $1-e^{-x}$ for $\lambda = 1$ therefore

$y = 1-e^{-x} \rightarrow 1-y = e^{-x} \rightarrow -\ln(1-y)=x$

just plug in your y's into this equation and you will get the associated exponential rv values.